# Updated contents and image not showing on site until browser cache cleared - Magento EE (REDIS)

Tags: magento, caching, redis

We having Magento Enterprise and using Redis for caching. any changes on site with contents, Images is not reflecting (old contents/images showing) until browser get cleared.

Please help me to find exact root cause, it this issue related to key expiry?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "contents", text? If the image paths are identical, then that would make sense why those don't change until the browser cache is cleared.

Comment: are you using Full Page Caching?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?